# Creating a object for a class which is in jar

Tags: java, object, jar, pojo

I have two projects. Project B is maven dependency in project A.I have to use a pojo class of project B in project A

Note:- I don't want to add the jar in build properties because in production it will be a issue

Comment: What is the actual question/issue?

Comment: I think my manager won't agree.

Comment: What is your quesiton?

Comment: Hey my problem was solved...they have created a constructor with protected...So I have created a new class which I have extended this class

Answer (score 0):

Its simple, you can packaging the project A as a jar and add this dependency as a provided scope in project B.

For example:

pom.xml (Project A):

```
<project>
...
<groupId>com.myproject.easy</groupId>
<artifactId>commom-lib</artifactId>
<version>0.1</version>
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

</project>
```

pom.xml (Project B - Needs to use some Pojo Class from Project A):

```
<project>
...

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.myproject.easy</groupId>
        <artifactId>commom-lib</artifactId>
        <version>0.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

</project>
```

It won't throw exception on your application server, cause provided scope means the jar used as a dependency in project B going to be on classpath during runtime.